# Swift - UI is reset when keyboard open

Tags: ios, user-interface, swift, keyboard, dispatch-async

I started to learn swift a few days ago and I have a big problem with the UI.
I have a function which sends data to a url and I want to update the UI when the data is arrived.
I tried to do it with dispatch async but when I tapped on a text filed and the keyboard is opened the UI is reset to the default UI as at the start point (in this case the btn returns to default y).

```
func loginConnect()
    {
        self.loginLoader.startAnimating();
        self.loginLoader.hidden = false;
        UIView.animateWithDuration(1, animations: {
            self.Loginbox.alpha = 0;
            self.loginBtn.alpha = 0;
        })
        var url1:NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://www.justaurl.com/login.php")!;
        println(url1);
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url1);
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST";
        let postString = "user=username&pass=password";
        request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
            data, response, error in

            if error != nil {
                println("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            //println("response = \(response)")
            var error: NSError?
            var responseString:NSString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!;
            let data = responseString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);
            let jsonData:NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers , error: &error) as NSDictionary;

            println(jsonData["0"] as String);
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                // Show the alert
                self.loginLoader.hidden = true;
                self.loginLoader.stopAnimating();
                UIView.animateWithDuration(1, animations: {
                    self.Loginbox.alpha = 1;
                    self.loginBtn.alpha = 1;
                }, completion:
                    {
                        completion in if 1 == 1
                        {
                            if((jsonData["0"] as String) == "error")
                            {
                                UIView.animateWithDuration(1, animations: {
                                    self.loginBtn.frame.origin.y = CGFloat(self.loginBtnDefaultY) + 15;
                                });
                            }

                        }
                        var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.5, target: self, selector: Selector("errorTxtAnimation"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false);
                    })
            })
            }
        }
        task.resume();
    }
```

Comment: This is because of auto layout. When using auto layout, you should not set any frames. If you do, the views will revert to the positions defined by their constraints whenever the view needs to redraw. You should change the position of any views by modifying the constant values of their constraints.

Comment: For what auto layout is used? and thanks!!

Comment: I'm not sure what your question means. I'm assuming that loginBtn was created in IB, and uses auto layout. Is that so?

Comment: I don't know what auto layout is doing, so i disable it in my project but for what i need to use it?

Comment: Auto layout is useful for many things, especially if you're making apps that need to work on all screen sizes. I suggest that you look at the videos about it from the 2012 WWDC.

Comment: So what i need to do if i want to use auto layout and also update the btn location like i did and it will saved?

Comment: You need to add a vertical constraint to the button in IB, and make an IBOutlet to it. In code, you modify the constraint's constant value and hen call layoutIfNeeded on its superview inside the animation block of animateWitDuration. Do some searching on SO to find some code examples.